# How to bulk convert html content of eml files to doc (Word) files

Tags: convert, format-conversion

I got over 5000 of eml files with html content (declared as text/html utf-8 in headers, but...) and I need to convert them to the only format our outsourced translator supports - Microsoft Word .doc

I can do it manually by openning it in Thunderbird and copy-paste it into openoffice, but that takes a lot of manual labor.

My last attemt was to extract html content using "munpack -t" command, but it somehow broke encoding. Even if I added meta header to html file defining utf-8 charset, it was broken. After closer look onto these eml files I am sure these are not utf-8, althroug defined as and thunderbird can read them fine.

Sadly, I cannot provide these files as they contain "sensitive company data". I hope someone will be able to recognize the problem or recommend a new tool.

**edit:** Sample file (with sensitive data erased) https://pastebin.com/qm1rBh7t

Comment: Do you think you can add a sample of one of your problematic eml files to your question?

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, **the 23 line text file would have better been added to your question**, rather than a link to it.  It minimizes the number of windows having to be opened to work with the question.  I'm not sure, but I believe Pastebin expires after a time.  If the text was included in the question it would remain available as part of the thread as long as the thread lives.

Answer (score 0):

never done it so no idea.  a quick search with a search engine found

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files-unix

which contains

- start quote

"One option is libreoffice/openoffice in headless mode (make sure all other instances of libreoffice are closed first):

libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt:text mydocument.doc

For more details see e.g. this link: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/

For a list of libreoffice filters see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/filter/source/config/fragments/filters

Since the openoffice command line syntax is a bit too complicated, there is a handy wrapper which can make the process easier: unoconv."

- end quote

I'd experiment with this for a single file, then just put in a `for` loop to do them all.  this is intended as idea, hoping it'll push you where I think may work (or at least lead to a fix)